# "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated" warning while iterating window object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Please consider the following code in html/javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var myObject = {};
    var mySecondReference = myObject;

    for (s in window)
      if (window[s]===myObject)
        alert("reference found: " + s);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

It iterates though the window object in order to search any references to a given object. It works fine everywhere, however in Chrome/ium gives me the following warnings:

```
'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
test.html:8 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.
```

Is it something I should be scared of (especially with future versions of chrome browser)?

How can I get rid of those messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something you have to worry about, If you don't want to see them, just filter it

```
var myObject = {};
var mySecondReference = myObject;

for (s in window)
  if (!/webkitStorageInfo|webkitIndexedDB/.test(s) && window[s]===myObject)
    alert("reference found: " + s);
```

Answer (score -5):

The error message tells you what you should do

> 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
>
> test.html:8 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.

So, instead of using `window.webkitStorageInfo`, use `window.webkitTemporaryStorage` or `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage`

You can check if these exist with something like this:

```
var storageInfo = null;

if(navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage) {
  storageInfo = navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage;
} else if(navigator.webkitPersistentStorage) {
  storageInfo = navigator.webkitPersistentStorage;
} else if (window.webkitStorageInfo) {
  storageInfo = window.webkitStorageInfo;
}
```

Same thing with the `indexedDB` deprecation message

```
var yourDB = null;

if(indexedDB) {
  yourDB = indexedDB;
} else if(webkitIndexedDB) {
  yourDB = webkitIndexedDB;
}
```