# How do I get all variables that have assigned to specific class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through out all variables that used one of my class, like `let Player = new GameObject("Player", 0, 0, 5, 5);`.

I've tried this

```
class GameObject {
    constructor(name, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY) {
         this.name = name;
         this.posX = posX;
         this.posY = posY;
         this.sizeX = sizeX;
         this.sizeY = sizeY;
    }
}

let Player = new GameObject("Player", 0, 0, 5, 5);
let Player2 = new GameObject("Player2", 0, 0, 5, 5);

for (let f in window) { 
     if (window[f] instanceof GameObject) {
         console.log("founded" + f);
     }
}
```

But only what I got is this warning:
`VM147:15 [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`

I even tried Google my issue, but I've found nothing useful.

```
class GameObject {
    constructor(name, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY) {
       this.name = name;
       this.posX = posX;
       this.posY = posY;
       this.sizeX = sizeX;
       this.sizeY = sizeY;
    }
}

let Player = new GameObject("Player", 0, 0, 5, 5);
let Player2 = new GameObject("Player2", 0, 0, 5, 5);

function update() {
    for (let f in window) { 
        if (window[f] instanceof GameObject) {
            console.log("founded" + f);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


update();
```

I expect the output of `Player1, Player2`, but the actual output is `VM147:15 [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`

Comment: No need for `let f` in the loop, just use `f in window`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated" warning while iterating window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060329/window-webkitstorageinfo-is-deprecated-warning-while-iterating-window-object)